# difference between two dates based on set format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

```js
const formatChatDate = (chatDate) => {
    // round to the nearest whole number
    const dt = Moment(chatDate).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // March 9th 2021, 7:16:16 pm;
   const dtNow = Moment(new Date()).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // March 9th 2021, 7:16:16 pm;
    const diffDate= Math.round((dt-dtNow)/(1000*60*60*24));
    if(diffDate.diff(dt,'days')<1){
        return dt.format("LT");  
    }else{
        return dt.format("LLL"); 
    }
};
```

**I need to calculate the difference between two dates and yesterday chat it will look like ll format and current date lt formate**

> I need to set 11.59pm mean ll format and 12pm mean lt format.. chatdate mean last message date and dtnow mean current date

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use moment's `diff` to calculate difference between dates? Something like:

```
const formatChatDate = (chatDate) => {
    const dt = moment(chatDate);
    const dtNow = Moment(new Date());
    
    if(dtNow.diff(dt,'days') < 1){
       return dt.format("LT");  
    } else {
       return dt.format("LLL"); 
    }
};
```

Comment: I need a different format yesterday mean it will show full date and time today mean .. time is enough

Comment: suppose 11.59 pm mean it will show full date and time but after 1.am it will consider same format because diff consider 24 hr

Comment: I think this solution shows exactly what you want: if `chatDate` compared to current date is less than a day, function returns only time. Else will return complete date.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const formatChatDate = (chatDate) => {
    if(!chatDate) return '';
   
    const dt =  Moment(chatDate);
    // dt.set({hour:0,minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0})

    const dtNow = Moment(new Date());
    if(dtNow.diff(dt, 'days') < 1) {
        console.log(dt.format("LT"));
        //console.log(dtNow);
       return dt.format("LT");
         // return chatDate;
        
    } else {

        return dt.format("LLL");
    }
};
```

[image][![

> march 8 2021 10.21 am and 11.12 pm same date but I got different format @Giovanni Esposito

][2]][2]

Comment: this one i tried earlier ..see my image @Giovanni Esposito

Comment: (image content)same date but I get a different format